# Storing LAB colors as integers

Tags: c#, serialization, colors, rgb

When using RGB values, .NET has built in ways for it to be converted from an integer and it's straightforward to convert a color to an int. Is there a way of storing LAB colors as integers instead? Unlike RGB, LAB color values can be negative. I don't want to have to store the colors in RGB and convert them at runtime if I can avoid it as I have no need for RGB values.

Comment: A negative integer is an integer too, why is that an issue for you ? The actual issue is that you get real values, instead of integers, right ? You surely can obtain integers from that, simply multiply the reals by some value like 100 and truncate, and accept that you lose some precision. I would be surprised if there was a RGB -> CIELAB purely in the integer domain with the same precision as the one that uses reals. Lastly, there are many ways to convert from RGB to CIELAB, since you are coming from a device-dependent space and going to an independent one.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, or I haven't explained it properly. I've converted my RGB to LAB values. How would I store these values in an XML file, for example, for later retrieval? With RGB, I'd use this `((r & 0x0ff) << 16) | ((g & 0x0ff) << 8) | (b & 0x0ff);` and store that value. Can I use this same method with the LAB values, or do the `16` and `8` values need to be changed? I'm new to this color stuff.

Comment: Are you saying you converted a packed integer representing RGB to CIELAB in a packed integer too ? It looks like you are not aware of the conversion between colorspace dependent and independent of device. To give any help, you need to show your conversion procedure.

Comment: I converted RGB -> XYZ, then XYZ -> LAB as described here http://www.easyrgb.com/index.php?X=MATH&M=15#text15 The conversion works as I've tested values with known results. I now have a LAB struct (with double L, double A, double B fields). This is where I'm up to at the moment. Is there a way to save this, accepting minor precision loss, into one integer value like I can with RGB structs? Thanks

Comment: Fine, that is better. Given the multiplications used in CIELab in the link provided by you, trying to pack this into a single 32 bit integer is likely to cause huge information loss. Is there some reason to simply not store them as 3 integers ? Multiply the doubles by some value, as mentioned before, and truncate.

Comment: I could store them as 3 integers if that's preferred. It's just that I've been given an existing codebase that would need refactoring since it assumes that it loads a single integer. But if 3 ints is the best way, I'll go ahead and do that. Thanks for your help (can post as answer and I'll accept).

Comment: Probably at some point I will check the range of the values obtained in CIELab by these transformations you are using and suggest some actual multiplication values before truncation. Then I will post that as an answer.

Comment: From what I can gather, they're between -128 and 127 (at least for the A and B values).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the transformation being done is RGB -> XYZ with the old 2 degree observer and CIE Standard Illuminant D65 -> CIELAB. The code, for reference, for performing that is given below (R, G, B  is assumed to be in [0, 1]).

Considering these transformations starting from 8 bits per channel in RGB, the range for L* is [0, 100], a* (-85.92, 97.96], b* (-107.54, 94.20]. These values are close approximations. In theory, a* and b* are unbounded, but you will find some places that talk about a limit of +-128, +-110, etc. My suggestion is then to simply sum 128 to each value, multiply it by 100, and then round to integer (that should be precise enough for a color). Any given L*a*b triplet can then be represented by a 16 bits unsigned integer.  You could pack them into a 64 bit integer. And after unpacking you would subtract 128 from each value. If you can keep three signed short integers, things get much simpler.

```
def rgb_xyz(r, g, b): # 2o. D65
    triple = [r, g, b]

    v, d = 0.04045, 12.94
    for i, c in enumerate(triple):
        triple[i] = 100 * (c / d if c <= v else ((c + 0.055)/1.055)**2.4)

    multipliers = (
            (0.4124, 0.3576, 0.1805),
            (0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722),
            (0.0193, 0.1192, 0.9505))

    x, y, z = [sum(row[i] * triple[i] for i in range(3))
            for row in multipliers]
    return x, y, z

def xyz_cielab(x, y, z):
    triple = [x, y, z]

    t0, a, b = 0.008856, 7.787, 16/116.
    ref = (95.047, 100.0, 108.883)
    for i, c in enumerate(triple):
        triple[i] /= ref[i]
        c = triple[i]
        triple[i] = c ** (1/3.) if c > t0 else a * c + b

    l = 116 * triple[0] - 16
    a = 500 * (triple[0] - triple[1])
    b = 200 * (triple[1] - triple[2])
    return l, a, b
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@mmgp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1832154/mmgp)'s answer, I decided to check whether multiplying by 100 and using `uint16`s per channel was enough. The answer is a definitive yes, and the lowest integer multiplier that the [below Python program](https://github.com/MyNameIsTrez/pixel-sorter/blob/master/extra/lab_uint.py) still passes its assert with is actually 82!

It relies on [this image](https://github.com/MyNameIsTrez/pixel-sorter/blob/master/input/all_colors.png) containing all 16 million RGB colors that was generated with [this Python program](https://github.com/MyNameIsTrez/pixel-sorter/blob/master/extra/generate_all_colors_image.py).

What is asserted here is that every single possible RGB color is losslessly translatable from RGB uint8s -> LAB doubles -> LAB uint16s -> LAB doubles -> RGB uint8s.

```py
# Verifies all_colors.png unsigned integer translation loses no information

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from skimage import color


def main():
    # "The L* values range from 0 to 100; the a* and b* values range from -128 to 127."
    # https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.lab2rgb
    signed_to_unsigned = 128

    # Unsigned integer precision loss compensation multiplier
    # 82 is the lowest integer value that works
    precision_compensation = 82

    print("Loading input RGB image")
    input_img = Image.open("input/all_colors.png").convert("RGBA")
    pixels = np.array(input_img, dtype=np.float32)

    print("/= 255")
    # I do [:, :, :3] everywhere so only RGB is affected, and not a potential A
    pixels[:, :, :3] /= 255

    print("Running rgb2lab()")
    pixels[:, :, :3] = color.rgb2lab(pixels[:, :, :3])

    print("+= signed_to_unsigned")
    pixels[:, :, :3] += signed_to_unsigned

    print("*= precision_compensation")
    pixels[:, :, :3] *= precision_compensation

    print("Rounding to uint32")
    pixels = np.round(pixels).astype(np.uint16)

    print("pixels.astype(np.float32)")
    pixels = pixels.astype(np.float32)

    print("/= precision_compensation")
    pixels[:, :, :3] /= precision_compensation

    print("-= signed_to_unsigned")
    pixels[:, :, :3] -= signed_to_unsigned

    print("Running lab2rgb()")
    pixels[:, :, :3] = color.lab2rgb(pixels[:, :, :3])

    print("*= 255")
    pixels[:, :, :3] *= 255

    print("Rounding to uint8")
    pixels = np.round(pixels).astype(np.uint8)

    assert (
        np.array(input_img, dtype=np.uint8) == pixels
    ).all(), "❌ There was loss of information during the translation!"

    print(" There was no loss of information during the translation!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```